# Calculating label size with calculateLabelSize of QgsPalLayerSettings in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, features, size

I want to calculate label size for specific features in the layer. I found `calculateLabelSize` function in `QgsPalLayerSettings`. When I use it QGIS crashes.

Here is my code (I run it from the code editor of the QGIS Python Console):

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QFontMetricsF

layer = iface.activeLayer()
f = next(layer.getFeatures())

labeling = layer.labeling()
labeling_settings = labeling.settings()

map_settings = iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings()
render_context = QgsRenderContext().fromMapSettings(map_settings)

font = QFont('Arial')
font.setPointSize(10)
fm = QFontMetricsF(font)

result = labeling_settings.calculateLabelSize(fm,'text', f, render_context)
print(result)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

P.S. My goal is to get the size of a specific feature label regardless of its position.

I think I solved this puzzle. The problem was in rule based symbology. I was using root labeling setting wich hasn't label settings, only filter settings. Later I'll attach my solution

Comment: Can you please provide a graphical explanation of your issue? Does each feature in your layer have different labelling?

Comment: @Taras For now i can get labels bboxes with QgsMapRendererParallelJob. But I dont need to render all the stuf. I just need to get size of labels bboxes. And I need it one by one. If label bbox is to big i'm changing label text. I dont know what to show in graphical explanation. The question is about how to make `calculateLabelSize` work.